# What's better to use for Django?

Tags: python, django

Django-rest or Django Pistons?

What's better plugin for API stuff?

Comment: Please provide your criteria for "better"?  Faster?  Cheaper?  More use of Oracle licensed products?

Comment: What's a better library in general.  Pistons has a lot of problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not used django-rest, but I have used django-piston and found it really effective and pretty easy to get up and running quickly.

It also seems to be a popular choice with a lot of devs I know - and it powers the API for bitbucket, which I take as a good sign.

For me, the primary pinch-points are:

- if you're looking to create hybrid representations of your data models (eg you want the standard User resource representation to show all the fields, but (as an example - I don't want to start a REST war here) you also want your Foo representation to show a limited, nested subset of User fields) then you have to write more complicated Resource definition code to do that, because the class-based setup only allows one representation of a given model that automatically gets reused whenever that resource is needed. (Which is actually a good thing, but can be a constraint if you have to bend the output a bit.)
- if any of your models store actual XML, you'll have to write a smart/non-escaping emitter to handle it, which is more about punching getting busy with your favourite XML library (tip: ElementTree)

Even with those two things in mind, piston has been my go-to resource for knocking up a quick API, and I've been very happy so far. I am tempted to try [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) next, though

Comment: "it powers the API for bitbucket" Interestingly, the guy who wrote Piston wrote BitBucket as well.

Comment: Is BitBucket built on Django?

Comment: @TIMEX yes, look at the last line of the page footer on bitbucket.org "We run Django 1.2.4 * Piston 0.2.3rc1 * Hg 1.7.2 * Python 2.7.0"

Comment: +1 not only for good answer but also mentioning django-tastypie

Answer (score 1):

I personally like Piston.  It seems like it's got an active mailing list and it is pretty customizable.  I like that is pretty flexible as to what type of output formats that you can request from it.  Also, creating your own authentication module is pretty easy. 
I haven't really used django-rest though.